# Multiplication operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am implementing a class Vector and defined the multiplication operator as a **member** of the class as

```
Vector operator*(const float& s);
```

as far as I understand, this means that the left operand is a `Vector` and the right operand is a `float`. So if I try and do something like this

```
Vector c(1,2,3);
Vector d = c * 2.0f; // Results in d = (2,4,6)
```

that's ok, however, to my eyes is weird to see first the vector then the scaling factor, so in order to have `float * Vector` I defined a **non-member** function as

```
Vector operator*(const float& s, const Vector& v)
{
    //Invalid operands to binary expression 'const Vector' and 'float'
    return v * s;
}
```

However I received the error in the comment. I don't know what am I missing or if this is not the way I should declare the operator in order to do the scaling in `float * Vector` fashion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that you're passing `v` as `const Vector &`, but your member `operator*` is not marked as `const`. So it can only be called on non-const `Vector` objects. This is most certainly *not* what you want, so just mark the member as `const`:

```
Vector operator*(const float& s) const;
```

Comment: So, my approach of making a non-member function to be able to do `float * Vector` is ok?   Now, should I have something like `Vector Vector::operator*(const float&s) const` ? I thought `const` after the parameter list only tells whether we are allowed to modify or not the attributes of a class.

Comment: @BRabbit27 Yes, your approach was correct; the only one, in fact. You might want to consider doing all 3 binary combinations as non-members, implemented using a member `*=`. But that's optional.

Comment: @BRabbit27 The `const` (and/or `volatile`) after the parameters controls the type of `*this`. So it also controls the type of reference on which you can invoke the function. If a function is not marked `const`, it cannot be invoked on a `const` object (precisely because it could modify the members).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Vector {
public:
    float x, y, z;

    Vector(float _x = 0.0f, float _y = 0.0f, float _z = 0.0f) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}

    // vector + vector
    Vector operator+(const Vector& v) const {
        return Vector(x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z);
    }

    // vector * float
    Vector operator*(float scalar) const {
        return Vector(x * scalar, y * scalar, z * scalar);
    }

    // This friend function does the magic of float * vector
    friend Vector operator*(float scalar, const Vector& v) {
        return v * scalar;
    }

    void print() const {
        cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Vector v1(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    Vector v2 = 2.0f * v1;
    v2.print(); // prints (2, 4, 6)
    return 0;
}
```